How to create dropdown combine with react-select and react laag library for positioning dropdown menu
enter image description here
I have a basic version of react-select dropdown component when i have multiple dropdown components in same page dropdown menu underneth second one. So how i positioning menu when there is no space in bottom menu should show top
codesanbox link

To create a dropdown menu using react-select and the react-laag library for positioning, you can follow these steps:
Install react-select and react-laag libraries in your project:
npm install react-select react-laag
Import the necessary components in your React component file:


import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useLayer, Arrow } from 'react-laag';
Create a custom dropdown menu component using the react-laag library:
const DropdownMenu = ({ triggerRect, children }) => {
  const { layerProps, renderLayer } = useLayer({
    overflowContainer: false,
    auto: true,
    placement: 'bottom-start',
    triggerOffset: 10,
    containerOffset: 10,
    arrowOffset: 16,
  });

  return (
    <>
      {renderLayer(
        <div {...layerProps}>
          <Arrow
            backgroundColor="#fff"
            borderColor="#ccc"
            borderWidth={1}
            size={8}
            roundness={0.5}
            layerSide="top"
            triggerRect={triggerRect}
            arrowStyle={{ marginTop: -1 }}
          />
          {children}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};



Use the custom dropdown menu component in your main component:


const MyComponent = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState(null);
  const [triggerRect, setTriggerRect] = React.useState(null);

  const options = [
    { value: 'option1', label: 'Option 1' },
    { value: 'option2', label: 'Option 2' },
    { value: 'option3', label: 'Option 3' },
  ];

  const handleSelectChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        options={options}
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={handleSelectChange}
        onMenuOpen={() => {
          const selectInput = document.querySelector('.react-select__input');
          setTriggerRect(selectInput.getBoundingClientRect());
        }}
      />
      {triggerRect && (
        <DropdownMenu triggerRect={triggerRect}>
          <div>
            {options.map((option) => (
              <div key={option.value}>{option.label}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </DropdownMenu>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



That's it.
I hope my answer will help you.

I changed my code with your answer. but when i click dropdown total component one away. i have updated with your answer in sandbox link. Please check it out if i made mistake or not
